# Using PostgreSQL CURRENT_DATE function with Node and pg-native

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am using Node with Express for an app. I am using a pg-native module to connect to PostgreSQL. I am trying to insert some data where I want to use the PostgreSQL `CURRENT_DATE` function. I know it works in PostgreSQL, but how do I make it work with pg-native and Node?

```
//regular db connection code..
//insert statement..
db.query ('INSERT INTO users( firstname, lastname, email, createddate) 
           VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) 
           RETURNING firstName, lastName, email', [user.username, user.firstname, user.lastname, 
           `CURRENT_DATE`], true)
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do I make it work with pg-native and Node?

Like this:

```
//regular db connection code..
//insert statement..
db.query('INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, email, createddate) 
           VALUES ($1, $2, $3, CURRENT_DATE) 
           RETURNING firstName, lastName, email', [user.username, user.firstname, user.lastname], true)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Drastic difference between pg and pg-native performance inserting bytea data**

*Schema:*

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
data bytea 
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_pkey ON test(id int4_ops);
```

*test.js:*

```
import fs from 'fs';
import pg from 'pg';

const image = fs.readFileSync('./test.jpg');

const main = async () => {
const client = new pg.native.Client();

await client.connect();

  let index = 1000;

 while (index--) {
 await client.query('INSERT INTO "test" (data) VALUES ($1) RETURNING id', [
  image
  ]);
 }

 await client.end();
};

 main();
```

*Evaluation:*

```
$ time node ./test.js
```